# Date and time calculations to track time using command line in Unix/Linux

Tags: bash

I'm looking for an easy way to track time I work on a project using the command line. I do

```
echo "$(date) : Start" >>worktime.txt
```

When I start working and

```
echo "$(date) : End" >>worktime.txt
```

When I stop working. The result is a file of the form:

```
kent@rat:~/work$ cat worktime.txt 
Fri Jan  2 19:17:13 CET 2009 : Start
Fri Jan  2 19:47:18 CET 2009 : End
Fri Jan  2 21:41:07 CET 2009 : Start
Fri Jan  2 22:39:24 CET 2009 : End
```

"Start" and "End" are meant as descriptions and could have been *any* other text. **It is certain** that every *odd* line contains a start date and time before : and every *even* line contains an end date and time.

What I would like to do is sum up my worked time by parsing the text file using bash, tr, sed, awk and the other common Unix/Linux tools. I prefer using this approach instead of using Python, Perl, Haskell, Java etc.

All ideas welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wilhelmtell has a great script, if you need to use a slightly modified version so that you can continue to use `$(date)` instead of `$(date +%s)` this will work in an identical fashion, just with an added line to reformat the times using `+%s`

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
while read LINE; do
  d1=$(echo $LINE |cut -c1-28);
  t1=$(date -d "$d1" +%s);
  read LINE
  d2=$(echo $LINE |cut -c1-28);
  t2=$(date -d "$d2" +%s);
  total=$(($total+$t2-$t1));
done
echo $(($total/(60*60))) hours
```

Comment: Nice improvement. Keeping the date and time information the way they were was important to me.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using the GNU coreutils, run `date +%s` instead.

```
echo $(date +%s) : Start
```

The %s placeholder is non-POSIX compliant and is specific to GNU date.  It is replaced by the number of seconds passed since epoch.  Next write a script that takes the differences and sums them up.  You'll do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

total=0
while read LINE; do
  t1=$(echo $LINE |cut -d' ' -f1)
  read LINE
  t2=$(echo $LINE |cut -d' ' -f1)
  total=$(($total+$t2-$t1))
done
echo "$(echo "scale=2; $total/(60*60)" |bc -l)" hours
```

If you call the script sum_time.sh then you can invoke the script with

`~$ ./sum_time.sh <worktime.txt`

Comment: Nice script and it seem solid, however I go with the improved version by Jehiah as my accepted answer as I need to keep the date & time information intact.

Answer (score 2):

The following awk script should do it (not tested though):

```
BEGIN {
    total_secs = 0
    FS = OFS = ":"
}

function snip_it() {
    $NF = ""; $0 = substr($0, 1, length($0)-1);
}

!(NR % 2) {
    snip_it();
    ("date -d \"" $0 "\" +%s") | getline start_secs
}

NR % 2 {
    snip_it();
    ("date -d \"" $0 "\" +%s") | getline end_secs
    total_secs += (end_secs - start_secs)
}

END {
    print "Total work time of " total_secs " seconds"
}
```

The key is that `date +%s` returns the amount of seconds since 1970, and `-d` specifies an alternative time/date, instead of `now`.

Comment: Is this awk?  I think that should be mentioned.  At first it looked like Bash, then I realized it was probably awk.

Comment: You do get my vote up, nice script. However I think the solution in pure bash was nice as well, so I'm putting it as my accepted answer (as it doesn't require awk and is of equal complexity level).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use something that already exists:

http://fossies.org/linux/misc/old/tt-1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I have time some day I'll look into it, presently I'm satisfied with this simple (and "guaranteed" bug free [it's so simple that I don't expect any bugs]) solution. :-)

Comment: somehow this isn't the tt i know anyhow :(

Comment: i changed the link to the one i meant

Comment: @sdaau: it's a game of whack-a-mole :)

Answer (score 1):

As the goal is to made an overall calculation like:

```
total= (FirstEnd - FirstStart ) + (ScndEnd - ScndStart)
```

which could be written:

```
total= - FirstStart + FirstEnd - ScndStart + ScndEnd ...
```

The only requirement is that there are only completed pairs in `worktime.txt` (each start do have a corresponding end).

There is a very quick way:

```
echo $(sed <worktime.txt 's/ : .*$//g'|date -f - +%s|xargs printf "-%s+%s")|bc
5302
```

This solution is really very quick, as there is only 3 fork at all, not depending on how-much dates have to be processed. All forks are done only 1 time.

This could be written:

```
echo $(
    sed <worktime.txt 's/ : .*$//g' |
        date -f - +%s |
        xargs printf "-%s+%s"
  ) | bc
```